# importing to tif

Tags: grass-gis

i am working on grass 6.4.4. i want to know the details of which GDAL version  grass is using.i want to use r.in.gdal.exe which is giving "no dlls found in water fall model" error message.remaining exes of gdal are working but this one has problem. may i know why this error is coming. i have set Osgeo4w path correctly. i am using grass gui version and customized console application. i want to import the data from grass local to tiff format. is it possible.if so please suggest me the steps.Is there any documentation for path setting and importing or exporting to different formats.

Comment: this link may not related to my question

Comment: Right, wrong question. I have deleted my answer here. Not sure where this message comes from (not from GRASS GIS I think). May it be that you have several GDAL installations on your machine?